# Auto-key cipher

Tags: encryption

Auto-key cipher:

$A = B = K = L = Z^*_n$ , $n \geq 2$. The keystream is given by $z_0 = K \in \mathcal{K}$, $z_n= x_{n−1}$ for $n \geq 1$.

The encrypted text is $y_0 = x_0+K, y_i= x_i + y_{i-1}$.

The question is: is this a good encrypting?
May somebody help me answer this question?

Comment: Hint: What if you know some part of the message?

Comment: note you defined key stream but didn't use it in the cipher. What you defined is totally broken as you wrote yi=xi+yi-1 and I suspect you meant to write yi=xi+zi which is much better and still very weak.